# How to set proxy settings in ubuntu software center?

Tags: software-center, proxy

I have been using windows 7 and to update windows i configured netsh winhttp settings by using command: netsh winhttp set proxy 10.0.0.21:3128. That worked for windows update and many other softwares. Is there a way i can put proxy settings  throughout the computer that would work for software center and other softwares?

Comment: What Ubuntu release are you running?

Comment: software center works with proxy settings of gnome follow this link
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2066862

Answer (score 3):

As [Mahyar Pasarzangene](https://askubuntu.com/users/117052/mahyar-pasarzangene) said, you can set the proxy using **System settings -> Network -> Network Proxy** and then choosing "Manual" proxy and setting your host and port no. and then applying the settings system-wide.

However, if you are using authenticated proxy, i.e. you have a username and password for your proxy, you need to set it as follows:

Open a terminal(<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd>) and then type the following:

```
sudo nano /etc/apt/apt.conf
```

and set your username and password as follows:

```
Acquire::http::proxy "http://username:password@host:port_no/";
Acquire::https::proxy "https://username:password@host:port_no/";
Acquire::ftp::proxy "ftp://username:password@host:port_no/";
Acquire::socks::proxy "socks://username:password@host:port_no/";
```

You will not have `username@password` when you open this document, but you should put **your** username and password as shown above, separated by a `:` and then separated by `@` with the host.

If you have any special characters in your password, replace it with its HTML code.

Answer (score 2):

Yes , Go to **Settings -> Network -> Network Proxy -> Manual -> Apply System Wide**

Comment: +1 because it makes the Software Center / Updates work over proxy. It's a pity that "Apply System Wide" doesn't do exactly what it says on the tin. I still can't ping www.google.com from my terminal, for example.

Comment: @TenLeftFingers: You can't ping when you are behind a proxy: http://superuser.com/questions/175428/how-to-ping-when-behind-a-proxy

Answer (score 0):

if you are using authenticated proxy then you can use this trick 
First go to **Sytem settings -> Network -> Network Proxy** 

choose "Manual" and write

`user:pass@proxy` (NOT ONLY PROXY)in proxy column and `port` in the port column.
Apply the settings **system wide**.

This may solve your problem.